# Firefox WebExtension options button not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm updating an old extension, passing from the old XUL code to html/css "chrome" code.

I have an issue with the "options_ui" tag in my .json file... if i load the extension using the current firefox version (46.0.1) i can't see the "options" button of the extension (as shown in about:addons).

But if i load it using the current developer version (48.0a2) it shows and works as espected.

[image: options button]

Any suggestion of how can i fix this?, there must be a way to show the options button without using XUL code.

This is the section of options_ui in my json file:

> "options_ui": {
>         "page": "html/options.htm"   },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem, here's what I found https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/04/29/webextensions-in-firefox-48/ .

Seems that Firefox WebExtensions will be fully functional from v.48, that's why the Options button is so far only visible in the developer version of Firefox.

Comment: If you find out the link to your options.htm you could open that directly until options_ui is supported.  Something like moz-extension://<Random Extension ID>/html/options.htm

Comment: @tube-builder it's a pity, that there is no info about it in the guideline.

Comment: Well i think i'll have to wait. Thank you!.